# Kill an SGE job "already in deletion", as user

Tags: gridengine

Is there a way that my users can kill their own jobs that are stuck in the **dr** state?

```
qstat -f <jobid>
```

as the user, returns

```
job <jobid> is already in deletion
```

yet when run as root it does get deleted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have `ENABLE_FORCED_QDEL` set as part of `qmaster_params` in your cluster configuration (see the `sge_conf(5)` man page), then users can run `qdel -f <jobid>` to force deletion of their own jobs.